# Trunk between SG200's doesn't seem to send tagged traffic (n00b)

Tags: networking, switch, vlan

I have a cisco SG200-26FP (switch A) connected to a cisco SG200-26P (switch B). I would like to use the existing link between both switches as a trunk so 2 VLANs can use this connection, but I'm running into some difficulties. As an extra hurdle, these devices don't allow connections via CLI, so it's only GUI I'm afraid...

Config switch A:

```
GE13: connection to switch B: Trunk: VLAN10 Untagged, VLAN50 Tagged
GE14: Access: VLAN50 Untagged
GE22: connection to router: General: VLAN10 Untagged, VLAN50 Tagged, VLAN51 Tagged
```

Config switch B:

```
GE20: Access: VLAN50 Untagged
GE26: connection to switch A: Trunk: VLAN10 Untagged, VLAN50 Tagged
```

Here's what I don't understand: on switch A, I can hang a device on port GE14 and it will receive an IP from the DHCP server on VLAN50, it will see the gateway, etc. However, on switch B, port GE20 doesn't receive an IP from the DHCP server. I can't see why and I feel I'm missing something obvious here.

Both switches hold at least one more VLAN (seperately), all is well there. There are also no issues with VLAN10.

[image: Switch A VLAN Membership Table]
[image: Switch B VLAN Membership Table]

If you need anymore info or screenshots, let me know.

Comment: As far as I am aware, there is a console port for configuration on each of these switches. Use the console port for your CLI.

Comment: Go check cisco's website for newer firmware.   We used to have a ton of these switches at my job and some of the SG200 series did eventually get SSH in the most recent firmware upgrades..